# Insert several array of value different in new row from database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

I want insert in the row from database, array of values as that each of they put in new row from database.

I not want insert all values in a row from database with use of serialize(json_encode or etc).

**For example:**(in this example, i want three times insert data(value), because i have 3 value different)
**Update 4:**

this my value:

```
<input name="name[0][]" value="11">
<input name="passport_number[0][]" value="11">


<input name="name[1][]" value="22">
<input name="passport_number[1][]" value="22">
```

i do it, but it not worked:

```
$name_input = $this->input->post('name');
$passport_number_input        = $this->input->post('passport_number');
//$term_passport_input = $this->input->post('term_passport');
//$date_of_birth_input       = $this->input->post('date_of_birth');
//$age_input        = $this->input->post('age');
//$national_number_input = $this->input->post('national_number');
//$mobile_input       = $this->input->post('mobile');
//$address_input        = $this->input->post('address');

$data = array();
foreach ($name_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name_input[0]
        'passport_number' => $passport_number_input[0],
        //'term_passport' => $term_passport_input[$idx],
        //'date_of_birth' => $date_of_birth_input[$idx],
        //'age' => $age_input[$idx],
        //'national_number' => $national_number_input[$idx],
        //'mobile' => $mobile_input[$idx],
        //'address' => $address_input[$idx],
    );
};
var_dump($name_input);
$this->db->insert_batch('customer_info', $data);
```

This is output '$name_input' with `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
    [0] = > array(1) {
        [0] = > string(2)"11"
    }[1] = > array(1) {
        [0] = > string(2)"22"
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message: Cannot
>   modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\admin\tour_foreign.php:405)
>   Filename: core/Common.php
>  Line Number: 413
>
> A Database
>   Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1054
>  Unknown column '0' in 'field
>   list'
>  INSERT INTO `customer_info` (`0`) VALUES ('22')
>   Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>  Line
>   Number: 330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 3: Per updated question (update 4)**
Looking at the `var_dump` of `$name_input` following code should work:

```
$name_input = $this->input->post('name');
$passport_number_input = $this->input->post('passport_number');

$data = array();
foreach ($name_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name_input[$idx][0],
        'passport_number' => $passport_number_input[$idx][0]
    );
};
$this->db->insert_batch('customer_info', $data);
```

It is further needed to access the [0] element as the POST input is passes as an `array of arrays`

**Update 2:**
Seeing the problem is because the POST returns the data as a further array following code MIGHT work. I would need `var_dump` of POST inputs (`$hi_input`..) to give the exact code.

```
$hi_input    = $this->input->post('hi');
$hello_input = $this->input->post('hello');
$how_input   = $this->input->post('how');

$data = array();
foreach ($hi_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'hi' => $hi_input[$idx][0],
        'hello' => $hello_input[$idx][0],
        'how' => $how_input[$idx][0]
    );
};
$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
```

The following code should work as I have tested it (I do not have CodeIgniter Installed). It does not use CodeIgniter to get post data.

```
$hi_input    = $_POST['hi'];
$hello_input = $_POST['hello'];
$how_input   = $_POST['how'];

$data = array();
foreach ($hi_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'hi' => $hi_input[$idx][0],
        'hello' => $hello_input[$idx][0],
        'how' => $how_input[$idx][0]
    );
}; 
$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
```

**Update :**
You can also do this using `$this->db->insert_batch();`, like this :

```
$hi_input    = $this->input->post('hi');
$hello_input = $this->input->post('hello');
$how_input   = $this->input->post('how');

$data = array();
foreach ($hi_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'hi' => $hi_input[$idx],
        'hello' => $hello_input[$idx],
        'how' => $how_input[$idx]
    );
};
$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
```

*Old answer*
The CodeIgniter documentation on insert - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert
states that the $data parameter is an associative array with column names as keys and data to insert as values.

So you need to call it once for each row. Thus
Try this:

```
$hi_input    = $this->input->post('hi');
$hello_input = $this->input->post('hello');
$how_input   = $this->input->post('how');

foreach ($hi_input as $idx => $name) {
    $data = array(
        'hi' => $hi_input[$idx],
        'hello' => $hello_input[$idx],
        'how' => $how_input[$idx]
    );
    $this->db->insert('table', $data);
};
```

Comment: Please see my post update, i have same error for `insert_batch`, how fix it?

Comment: @EmmyCharles could you output the contents of $data array after te array, and check what's in it. Also there was a slight error in my code with `insert_batch`. I have updated my answer. Also the error you posted suggests it is because the `insert` is trying to convert the array into string and the key is taken as `0`. Have you tried putting the insert within the foreach, as in my second code example ?

Comment: Ok, i changed it, i get new error. you can see new error and output code in my first post. what is your comment?

Comment: @EmmyCharles It seems the `post` is returning an array in place of a string. The last piece of information I need to give you a working piece of code id `print_r` of `$hi_input`, `$hello_input`and `$how_input`. But without that also maybe referring to an index in the foreach like this `$hi_input[$idx][1]` might work.

Comment: it don't worked. what is your comment about use of following code:(how use it in my code)

    `$sql = array(); 
         foreach( $data as $row ) {
      $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['text']).'", '.$row['category_id'].')';
         }
         mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text, category) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));` see code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2NJy8/

Comment: the non CodeIgniter code i posted above should work fine. What is the error you are getting with it ? also can you please add to your question the `var_dump` of `$hi_input`. Also the code you just posted in your comment - it does not seem related to this question.

Comment: Please see my post in `Update 4`, put there and original code here. Put them here. tell me ...

Comment: Thanks, it get values but don't work insert, it have new error for database:Please see this error and tell me: http://pastebin.com/MUEMwJCq

Comment: @EmmyCharles The insert statement is failing because you are trying to insert a duplicate value in a KEY column. For this I would need the structure of `customer_info` table. Also I would suggest you accept this answer as it solves the PHP side of the problem and you have a properly formatted array and working `inert_batch()`. And open a new one with the SQL problem.